# JQuery find nearest element value to current time then addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list with animal feeding times, and i would like to highlight (css class) the next upcoming feeding based on the current time.

The List (shortened):

```
<ul id="feedingTimes">
    <li><time value="1000">10:00</time> Uhr Humboldtpinguine</li>
    <li><time value="1000">10:00</time> Uhr Anakondas + Alligatoren</li>
    <li><time value="1100">11:00</time> Uhr Königspinguine</li>
    <li><time value="1130">11:30</time> Uhr Pelikane</li>           
</ul>
```

I would paste some JQuery here but I couldn't come up with a nearly working solution so far.
It might be something like "find the value from the list which is closest to the current time then add a class". I don't know how to code that.

Help would be great, cheers!

Comment: if it's 10:30 or 11:15 what would be the correct option? what the format for 9:00? `09:00` or `9:00` ?

Comment: Show us your effort made towards this.!

Comment: If it is 10:00 would both Penguins and Snakes be highlighted?

Comment: The Time tag is only supported by Fx22+ and Opera currently

Comment: What about am/pm?  Are these dates at night or during the day?  Are you using 24 hour time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('time').attr('value') > (new Date().getHours() * 100) + new Date().getMinutes()) {
        $(this).addClass('next');
        return false;
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AVg7q/)

Comment: Brilliantly simple ... though does not work if two animals have same feeding time.

Comment: @Ruskin You can just add a class for each group of lis that you want. I was just doing a quick example.

Comment: You may want a >=  instead

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking qwertymk's great answer works:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var timeval = $(this).find('time').attr('value');
    if (timeval > (new Date().getHours() * 100) + new Date().getMinutes()) {
        $('li time[value="' + timeval + '"]').parent().addClass('next');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Not that pretty or elegant though.

Comment: Will these answers work once we are past the feeding times?  For example, lets say it is 14:00 (using 24 hour clock).  At that point I do not believe any would be selected, where the actual next feeding time is 10:00

Comment: Thanks for the amendment Ruskin! Works great :) @KevinBowersox you are right, nothing will be selected

Comment: Ah, but at 1400 there are no more feeding times that day ... which I would guess is the use-case for this problem - punters are not going to stay over at the zoo :D